# Powershell Script loop output to txt file

Tags: excel, powershell, text

I am using a Powershell script to write to a text file.  A client showed me this Powershell script to use to replace a excel macro I used to use...

```
$computers= gc "C:\Users\Powershell\DeviceList.txt"
foreach ($computername in $computers)
{
write-output "<$computername>
      active = yes
      group = 
      interval = 5min
      name = $computername
      host = $computername
      community = 
      version = 1
      timeout = 0
      retries = default
      port = 161
      qos_source = 1
</$computername>"  | Out-File -filepath "C:\Users\Powershell\Cisco_Mon.txt" -append
}
```

It works great but now I wanted to build on it to add additional variables.  In a perfect world I would like it to read from an excel spreadsheed grabbing each rowof data and each column being defined as a variable.  For now using another text file is fine as well.  Here is what I started with (it doesnt work) but you can see  where I am going with it...

```
$computers= gc "C:\Users\Powershell\devicelist.txt"
$groups= gc "C:\Users\Powershell\grouplist.txt"
foreach ($computername in $computers) + ($groupname in $groups)
{
write-output "<$computername>
      active = yes
      group = $groupname
      interval = 5min
      name = $computername
      host = $computername
      community = 
      version = 1
      timeout = 0
      retries = default
      port = 161
      qos_source = 1
</$computername>"  | Out-File -filepath "C:\Users\Powershell\Cisco_Mon.txt" -append
}
```

Of course it is not working.  Essentially I would LOVE it if I could define each of the above options into a variable from an excel spreadsheet, such as $community, $interval, $active, etc.

Any help with this would be very much appreaciated.  If someone could show me how to use an excel spreadsheet, have each column defined as a variable, and write the above text with the variables, that would be GREAT!!!.

Thanks,

smt1228@gmail.com

An Example of this would be the following...

Excel Data: (Colums seperated with "|"

```
IP | String | Group
10.1.2.3 | Public | Payless
```

Desired Output:

```
<10.1.2.3>
      active = yes
      group = Payless
      interval = 5min
      name = 10.1.2.3   
      host = 10.1.2.3   
      community = 
      version = 1
      timeout = 0
      retries = default
      port = 161
      qos_source = 1
</10.1.2.3>
```

Addition:

Pulling data from CSV for IP, String, Group where data is as follows in CSV...

```
10.1.2.3,public,group1
10.2.2.3,default,group2
10.3.2.3,public,group3
10.4.2.3,default,group4
```

to be writting into a .txt file as

```
IP = 10.1.2.3.
String = public
Group = Group1
```

and look for each line in the CSV

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new answer now. The easiest way would be to save your Excel document as CSV so that it looks like this (i.e. very similar to how you presented your data above):

```
IP,String,Group
10.1.2.3,Public,Payless
```

You can still open that in Excel, too (and you avoid having to use the Office interop to try parsing out the values).

PowerShell can parse CSV just fine: with `Import-Csv`:

```
Import-Csv grouplist.csv | ForEach-Object {
  "<{0}>
    active = yes
    group = {1}
    interval = 5min
    name = 10.1.2.3   
    host = 10.1.2.3   
    community = 
    version = 1
    timeout = 0
    retries = default
    port = 161
    qos_source = 1
  </{0}>" -f $_.IP, $_.Group
}
```

I'm using a format string here where `{0}`, etc. are placeholders. `-f` then is the format operator which takes a format string on the left and arguments for the placeholders on the right. You can also see that you can access the individual columns by their name, thanks to Import-Csv.

Comment: Then please add to your question what your input looks like and what you need to do with it. Just going from non-working code is a little difficult.

Comment: If it might be easier to explain I can acutally show you via a webex or even an email if you have time.  I really appreaciate your help

Comment: just edited hopefully that makes more sense.  Thanks for the help

Comment: it kind of worked, its not inputting the variables...I guess to better explain, how would I pull data from excel and write into a txt file.  See orig post for more info...

Comment: I am sooo close to getting this but for some reason I cannot get the variables to enter.  I got it to run but for soem reason each of the variables are blank in the output.

Comment: I still consider reasing the values from an Excel spreadsheet to be misguided. It overcomplicates things and PowerShell isn't really made for that.